# Sorting names based on letter in python

Tags: python, sorting

How to sort this based on a letter provided? Here the letter is `'A'`. So:

```
Input: 'Sonu Kumar,Rajesh Jo,Bhai Sahab,RH,Rk Aju,Abhi KK,Goharjha Ara,Avinash Kumar'
Required Output: 'Avinash Kumar,Abhi KK,Goharjha Ara,Rk Aju,Rajesh Jo,Bhai Sahab,Sonu Kumar'
```

The sorting is to be done on the list on names with following priorities:

1. Names with first name starting with the provided letter should come first.
2. Names with second name starting with provided letter should come second.
3. Names that contains the the word should come after that.

Names which do not contain the letter should be omitted. **Strictly 1 array should be used.** Any other algorithms are welcomed. Please make it pythonic if you can.

Following is my code:

```
#letter
letter='A'
#name list
names='Sonu Kumar,Rajesh Jo,Bhai Sahab,RH,Rk Aju,Abhi KK,Goharjha Ara,Avinash Kumar'
#fitting them in an array, and removing the names which do not contain the letter
ordered=[j for j in names.strip(' ').split(',') if letter.lower() in j.lower()]

#to sort names according to the appearance order of letter
def FSort(elem):
    return elem.lower().find(letter.lower())
#to sort names so that second names starting with provided letter comes first
def SSort(elem):
    return elem.find(' '+letter)
#to sort names so that first names starting with provided letter comes first
def TSort(elem):
    return elem.lower().find(letter)

ordered=sorted(ordered,key=FSort)
ordered=sorted(ordered,key=SSort) #this is not working as expected
ordered=sorted(ordered,key=TSort) #final output can be a list, here ordered
```

Comment: That `RH` is making problems.

Comment: I don't think so. RH is getting removed with 3rd line of code itself.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the second `sorted()` call spoils the results of the first `sorted()` call.

Comment: I would iterate through the list of names once, dropping each in one of three buckets (or none). I take it when you say must use one array, you are trying to force this to be unwisely done by a python sort, merely as an academic exercise in writing custom sorts? I modified this to work by writing one key function, and sorting once. As a hint, the key function only has three possible return values, and works very much like how you would explain the algorithm to a rubber ducky. Good luck :)

Comment: Oh, bonus material, I took the name.lower().split(' ') so it is easy to find the first name (index 0) and last name (index -1). Also you are not looking at the first letter of anything. If you have a first_name = 'Aju' then the first letter is first_name[0]. Just make sure you validate lengths.